# range loop and type info variation

Tags: go

Please consider below go code, also here: https://play.golang.org/p/I6oNJ8comc0

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := "someBird"
    for i := range a {
        va := a[i]
        fmt.Printf("%c va type: %T\n", va, va)
    }
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    for _, va := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%c va type: %T\n", va, va)
    }
}
```

When the 1st loop runs, the type info is `uint8`:

```
s va type: uint8
o va type: uint8
..
```

When the 2nd loop runs, the type info on the seemingly same item is `int32`:

```
s va type: int32
o va type: int32
..
```

I am confused, why is this? What kind of sorcery is this? Please explain to me, thanks!

Comment: Hi, interesting, per the [docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements), "For a string value, the 'range' clause iterates over the Unicode code points", whereas a simple array lookup returns the byte value at that position.

Comment: @IronMan, thanks, can you add it as answer please? will mark it as the accepted

Answer (score 3):

This is expected according to the [Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types). A Go string is just a sequence of bytes (`uint8`).

When you index into a string like `str[i]`, you get its raw bytes.

A `range` loop, on the other hand, *decodes* runes (UTF-8 code points) for you. It's doing `utf8.DecodeRuneInString` automatically.

A more interesting example would be text with multi-byte characters:

```
const nihongo = "日本語"
for index, runeValue := range nihongo {
    fmt.Printf("%#U starts at byte position %d\n", runeValue, index)
}
```

This will print:

```
U+65E5 '日' starts at byte position 0
U+672C '本' starts at byte position 3
U+8A9E '語' starts at byte position 6
```

[This Go blog post about Strings, bytes, runs and characters](https://blog.golang.org/strings) explains everything very well.